# Mongo won't start. Getting cryptic Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to start up my computer's mongodb service and it wouldn't start. I spent over an hour trying to debug it during which time I tried many solutions. Trying all of them may have messed up my mongo install, but I tried reinstalling mongo to get a fresh start. That didn't work either. I now have the following error and cannot find anything on google about how to fix it.

```
2017-06-01T16:57:02.339-0400 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15070 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=moss-greenelab
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.13
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 23899209cad60aaafe114f6aea6cb83025ff51bc
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-06-01T16:57:02.343-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
2017-06-01T16:57:02.361-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-06-01T16:57:02.361-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=18G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-06-01T16:57:02.364-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (13) [1496350622:364565][15070:0x7f80e0292c80], connection: /var/lib/mongodb/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002: file-remove: unlink: Permission denied
2017-06-01T16:57:02.383-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:13: Permission denied
2017-06-01T16:57:02.383-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 13: Permission denied, terminating
2017-06-01T16:57:02.383-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What command do you execute in Ubuntu terminal that throws that error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the telling part of the log:

```
/var/lib/mongodb/journal/WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002: file-remove: unlink: Permission denied
```

So have a look at `ls -la /var/lib/mongodb/journal` and see what the permissions on those files are. I'm betting that those (an probably others) are not properly owned by the correct user, which is normally `mongodb` on Ubuntu.

Assuming you've got an issue with ownership there, you can just run `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`.

If that doesn't work, as a last resort you can always just wipe out your data directory (assuming you don't need your data!) by running `rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/*`.